# Extract a set of continuous words which match pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to extract as set of continuous word which appear in a regular expression using javascript.

lets say I have string str = "I have **one thousand forty** rupees and you have **twenty five** rupees";

```
var pattern = 'one|thousand|forty|twenty|five';
```

I want regular expression to extract 'one thousand forty' and 'twenty five' together.Then I need to convert numeric equivalent of these and substitute back.

What I tried -

```
var regexp = new RegExp('('+pattern+')+', "g");
str.replace(regexp, function (all, matched) {
        alert (matched);
});
```

But it will give individual word.

**Please consider 'log((one thousand forty)+sin(twenty))' type of string with any complexity into account while designing solution.**

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do my job with below code. It works..!!! Hence I am answering my own question.

Thanks for all the help.

```
var regexp = new RegExp('((('+pattern+')\\s?)+)', "g");
str.replace(regexp, function (all, matched) {
        alert (matched);
});
```

Comment: To get a whole word match of your words, you could do `var pattern = /\b(?:one thousand forty|twenty(?: five)?)\b/g;` See http://www.regex101.com/r/fM9bD2

Comment: @Keith Grout -- actually there was an answer previously.But later it got deleted...lol.. :)